# I'm trying to peek my old backups

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 5s, I have had this phone since 2014. It is pretty beaten up... But it still works. My question is;
If I accidentally restore an older back up on my phone, will I be able to go back into iTunes and restore the most recent back up to get all my current information back on my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you have a more recent backup you can always restore that later.